# How to write a file in new line using java code

Tags: java, string

I having a text like **Apple|MicroSoft|Oracle|Windows|Mac|**.I wish to print like
Apple
Microsoft
Oracle
Windows
Mac.

I used **.split()** keword, but it prints like,
A
p
p
l
e
|
M
i
c
r
o
s
o
f
t
|
...

why it will print like this if any alternate solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you're trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
String name = "Apple|MicroSoft|Oracle|Windows|Mac|";
name = name.replaceAll("\\|", " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example, just use [replace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) to switch out the | characters with spaces

Comment: i cant change the | with space because it related with another Operation

Comment: @BenDennison: I meant using the replace() method, not changing it in the original string

Comment: @Ben, why not? Pepsi's algorithm gives exactly what you asked for: `yourString.replaceAll("|", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

If using the split() function, try `.split("|")`

Comment: ya, i already used this will i'm using .split("|") it prints like this A p p l e |

Comment: ya, i already use this, while i using this it prints like this, A P P L E | M I C R O S O F T...

Comment: If you split on the pipe then you will have to join with a space.  It's better to do the `replaceAll`.